# Creating onkeyup event on form element without actually keying up

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

Not even sure if that's possible, but what I'm trying to do is customize the WooCommerce Measurement Calculator. I was able to create it seperately with jQuery, but for some reason, the fields don't even display when I implement it to my Woocommerce site. But using javascript, it works.

Here's more details....
Site: http://www.steelbuildingcomponents.com/product/10x28c-eave/
Select any gauge. 3 text fields show up, "feet", "inches" and "Length you require" is underneath (have not gotten to the cosmetics of it yet). WooCommerce's Measurement Calculator doesn't allow you to utilize 2 fields for feet and inches. It does allow decimals (ex: .5 feet will calculate to 6 inches in price) We sell sheeting and it's highly doubtful our customers will know how to convert 6'8" into a decimal. So I'm trying to incorporate 2 fields that will add feet and inches together, and then populate it into the "Length you require" field. Simple enough, right?  Actually, it works. But the WooCommerce feature works if you type a number into the "Length you require field" a keyup event triggers and it shows final price below. Is there a way to make a keyup event into that field without the user actually keying up?  If it works, I'll eventually hide the "Length you require" field, which is why I'm trying to make it work this way.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work? Any better suggestions? Appreciate anything now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, then it's as simple as adding the [`.trigger("keyup")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or [`.keyup()`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) (no parameters) to the element.

Using plain JS, you can use [`.dispatchEvent("keyup")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Example usage:

```
// using jQuery
$("input#someInput").keyup();
// plain JS
document.querySelector("input#someInput").dispatchEvent("keyup");
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Lam, but I must be using the wrong syntax because I'm getting "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is null." message....

Comment: Here's my HTML

<input type="number" class="qty1" id="feets" value="" placeholder="Feet" onblur="myFunction()" style="float:left;" />
<input type="number" class="qty1" id="inches" value="" placeholder="Inches" onkeyup="myFunction()" />

<input type="number" data-unit="ft" data-common-unit="ft" name="length_needed" id="length_needed" class="amount_needed" autocomplete="off">

Comment: Javascript

function myFunction(){
                var feets = document.getElementById("feets").value;
                var inches = document.getElementById("inches").value;
    var inchconvert = inches/12;
    var newinches = parseFloat(Math.round(inchconvert * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
               // var sum = +feets + +inches;
       var sum= +feets + +newinches;
                
                document.getElementById("length_needed").value = sum;
    document.querySelector("input#length_needed").dispatchEvent("keyup");
                }

Comment: Sorry for the ugliness... total newbie here... please bear with me.

Comment: Don't Worry @Tony. I'll get back to you soon. Let me check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Thanks for the suggestion, @Jonathan Lam :)  Here's the code...

```
function myFunction(){
            var feets = document.getElementById("feets").value;
            var inches = document.getElementById("inches").value;
            var inchconvert = inches/12;
            var newinches = parseFloat(Math.round(inchconvert * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
           // var sum = +feets + +inches;
            var sum= +feets + +newinches;

            document.getElementById("length_needed").value = sum;

            textbox = document.getElementById("length_needed")

              var evt = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");

              var keyEventFunction = (evt.initKeyboardEvent ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent");

            evt[keyEventFunction](
                               "keyup",
                                true, 
                                true, 
                                window, 
                                false, 
                                false, 
                                false, 
                                false,
                                32, 
                                0 
            );

            textbox.focus();
            textbox.dispatchEvent(evt);

            }
```